# Center vertically textview inside a list item

Tags: android, layout

I'm developing an Android 2.3.3 application which has a listview.

This is list layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gatesLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAddGate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/add_r"
            android:contentDescription="@string/layoutEmpty"
            android:onClick="onAddGateClick" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnDeleteGate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/delete_n"
            android:contentDescription="@string/layoutEmpty"
            android:onClick="onDeleteGateClick" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gateTypeImage"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:contentDescription="@string/layoutEmpty" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gateNameText"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/gateSelectedCheck"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know how to make `gateNameText` text center vertically. I get it on top of the left upper corner.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `android:gravity` like this:

```
TextView
        android:id="@+id/gateNameText"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to use:

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this list_item.xml::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gateTypeImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="layoutEmpty" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gateNameText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/gateTypeImage"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="ABCDEFGH"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/gateSelectedCheck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_weight=".1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```